# Сбой в загрузке модели vosk на ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, vosk

Я взял свой код который запускался на windows10 и перенёс на сервер ubuntu и vosk перестал загружать модель
(выдаёт такую ошибку)

```
ERROR (VoskAPI:Model():model.cc:122) Folder '/root/APIalina-ai/vosk-model-ru-0.22' does not contain model files. Make sure you specified the model path properly in Model constructor. If you are not sure about relative path, use absolute path specification.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stt.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = vosk.Model("/root/APIalina-ai/vosk-model-ru-0.22")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/vosk/__init__.py", line 57, in __init__
    raise Exception("Failed to create a model")
Exception: Failed to create a model
```

код:

```py
import vosk
import sys
import queue
import json

model = vosk.Model("/root/APIalina-ai/vosk-model-ru-0.22")
samplerate = 44100


def va_listen(audio ): #callback
    rec = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, audio)

    while True:
        data = audio(44100)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
            res = json.loads(rec.Result())
            text = res['text']
            return text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как оказалось просто не вся модель была в папке(походу просто не вся загрузилась на сервер)

Answer (score 1):

Ну и как ты понял эту ошибку?
Укажи верный путь здесь:

```
model = vosk.Model("/root/APIalina-ai/vosk-model-ru-0.22")
```

Comment: Вообще говоря, ошибка "Failed to create a model" может означать что угодно. Модель создать не удалось, а почему - не сказано же.

Comment: Да 100% путь не верный указан